# django cms - integrate cms and differentiate content via something other than language

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

New to django...

I have a site with structure /[flavor]/[page] where there are many different flavors and each flavor has roughly the same set of pages.  At least at a simple level, this seems to work fine as a django app - flavor can easily become an input to the template for a page.

Now I'm trying to integrate some cms mojo so someone non-technical can easily add/modify content or pages per flavor, and it's not clear how/if django-cms supports this.  As far as I can tell, what I want seems similar or equivalent to how django-cms handles languages - in the admin there's a separate tab for each language where you can specify content per language.

For now, my site is English only, so I suppose one option (that doesn't seem too attractive or permanent) is to handle the flavors by pretending they're languages.

I know I can host an arbitrary django app on a cms page that could handle the flavor portion, but the hosted apps don't seem to support adding cms page within them in the same way that languages do.

Being new to django, I'm not wedded to a particular cms, and am open to any suggestions about approach, site structure, etc. as well - the main requirement is to support someone non-technical easily adding/modifying different content/pages for the different flavors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to bypass the CMS for the flavor pages and create a Flavor model instead.  You could use django-tinymce's HTMLField (https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/blob/master/docs/usage.rst) to allow rich text editing on Flavor fields.